# wordpress get posts from a category

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hi Im trying to make my first wordpress website. i have been trying to bring bat posts from two different categories and display them on the same page. I have it bring the posts back but  it keeps putting them in a random order. im wanting a  with posts from one categorie and a  underneath with posts from another category.

heres what i have got so far

```
<?php get_head(); ?>

<div id="container">
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_banner(); ?>

    <div class=" center content" role="main">
      <div id="posts">


          <div class="news">
                <?php query_posts('catname=news&showposts=3'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); the_title(); the_content(); 
                endwhile;?>

                <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
             <div class="msghead">
            <?php query_posts('catname=msghead&showposts=1'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); the_title(); the_content(); 
            endwhile;?>

           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebardiv">
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the order and orderby query parameters?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Your code might go something like this which orders by date, descending:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=news&showposts=3&orderby=date'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); the_title(); the_content(); 
endwhile;?>
```

Comment: this is good advice and would work but for some reason it isn't working i'm sure its because i have done something wrong in my code but just cant figure it out

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. You could try experimenting ordering by other fields as well to see if it changes anything. Is the HTML output ordered correctly at least? Maybe it's a display issue.

Comment: sorry my issue it was becasue i was using catname= intead of cat=

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't catch that for ya.